# Configuring database in grails - handling exception

Tags: grails, exception, datasource

I am using two datasources in my Grails application. One is my local db and the other is remote db as shown below.

```
development {
   dataSource {
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testax_dev?autoreconnect=true"
      properties {
         ...
      }
   }

   dataSource_phpscheduler {
      driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
      username = "xyz"
      password = "zxyz"
      url = "jdbc:mysql://remote-ip:3306/phpscheduler?autoreconnect=true"
   }
}
```

Now I want to handle the exception caused due to the connection problem of remote database so that the application starts successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Grails application will not start if the dataSource bean(s) can't be created. There is no way to start the application if the connection to the database fails.

The reason for this is that Grails depends on those beans being instanced, and ready.

**Update**

As pointed out by Burt Beckwith it is [possible](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312) to do [this](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1565), but it does require you to understand the lifecycle of Hibernate and your datasource. It's also possible to register your own `dataSource` which has error handling. As always, we owe much to Burt.

Comment: Not true. See http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1565. You could also easily register your own `dataSource` bean with error handling.